Add Score To the Another Actvity
'I am Making an Earning App
I Added Spin wheel "spinner Activity" but  the score counter is on "Main Activity" so i want to Add Coins On Textview which is present in Main Activity
MAIN ACTIVITY
And This Is my spinner Activity code
but when i run this score app crashes only when i click on spin the wheel button in xml'
CardView redeem;
CardView watchad;
CardView shareit;
CardView spinner;



private static final String PREFS_NAME = "SavedValue";
private static final String COIN_COUNT_KEY = "coinCount";
private TextView coinTextView;
private int coinCount;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    redeem = findViewById(R.id.reddemm);
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    coinTextView = findViewById(R.id.txt45);
    shareit = findViewById(R.id.shareit);
    watchad = findViewById(R.id.watchad);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    coinCount = prefs.getInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, 0);
    coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));


    redeem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,redeem.class));
        }
    });
    spinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,spinner.class));
        }
    });
    shareit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            coinCount += 500;
            coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, coinCount);
            editor.apply();


        }
    });



    watchad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

}

}



private static final String PREFS_NAME = "SavedValue";
private static final String COIN_COUNT_KEY = "coinCount";

private TextView coinTextView;
private int coinCount;




List<LuckyItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
private int coin;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);


    coinTextView = findViewById(R.id.txt45);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

    coinCount = prefs.getInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, 0);

    coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
    final LuckyWheelView luckyWheelView = findViewById(R.id.luckyWheel);
    findViewById(R.id.play).setEnabled(true);
    findViewById(R.id.play).setAlpha(1f);


    LuckyItem luckyItem1 = new LuckyItem();
    luckyItem1.text = "5";
    luckyItem1.color = Color.parseColor("#8574F1");
    data.add(luckyItem1);

    LuckyItem luckyItem2 = new LuckyItem();
    luckyItem2.text = "20";
    luckyItem2.color = Color.parseColor("#8E84FF");
    data.add(luckyItem2);

    LuckyItem luckyItem3 = new LuckyItem();
    luckyItem3.text = "30";
    luckyItem3.color = Color.parseColor("#752BEF");
    data.add(luckyItem3);

    LuckyItem luckyItem4 = new LuckyItem();
    luckyItem4.text = "0";
    luckyItem4.color = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.Spinwell140);
    data.add(luckyItem4);

    LuckyItem luckyItem5 = new LuckyItem();
    luckyItem5.text = "50";
    luckyItem5.color = Color.parseColor("#8574F1");
    data.add(luckyItem5);

    LuckyItem luckyItem6 = new LuckyItem();
    luckyItem6.text = "100";
    luckyItem6.color = Color.parseColor("#8E84FF");
    data.add(luckyItem6);

    LuckyItem luckyItem7 = new LuckyItem();
    luckyItem7.text = "200";
    luckyItem7.color = Color.parseColor("#752BEF");
    data.add(luckyItem7);

    LuckyItem luckyItem8 = new LuckyItem();
    luckyItem8.text = "0";
    luckyItem8.color = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.Spinwell140);
    data.add(luckyItem8);

    luckyWheelView.setData(data);
    luckyWheelView.setRound(getRandomRound());

    findViewById(R.id.play).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int index = getRandomIndex();
            luckyWheelView.startLuckyWheelWithTargetIndex(index);

            findViewById(R.id.play).setEnabled(false);
            findViewById(R.id.play).setAlpha(.5f);
        }
    });
    luckyWheelView.setLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener(index -> {
        if (index ==1 ){
            coin = 5;

            coinCount += 5;

            coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, coinCount);
            editor.apply();

        } if (index ==2 ){
            coin = 20;
            coinCount += 20;

            coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, coinCount);
            editor.apply();
        } if (index ==3 ){
            coin = 30;
            coinCount += 30;

            coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, coinCount);
            editor.apply();
        } if (index ==4 ){
            coin = 0;
            coinCount += 0;

            coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, coinCount);
            editor.apply();
        } if (index ==5){
            coin = 50;
            coinCount += 50;

            coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, coinCount);
            editor.apply();
        } if (index ==6 ){
            coin = 100;
            coinCount += 100;

            coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, coinCount);
            editor.apply();
        } if (index ==7 ){
            coin = 200;
            coinCount += 200;

            coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, coinCount);
            editor.apply();
        } if (index ==8 ){
            coin = 0;
            coinCount += 0;

            coinTextView.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(COIN_COUNT_KEY, coinCount);
            editor.apply();

        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("+ " + coin +" Coins"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        findViewById(R.id.play).setEnabled(true);
        findViewById(R.id.play).setAlpha(1f);
    });


}


private int getRandomIndex() {
    int[] ind = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(ind.length);
    return ind[rand];
}

private int getRandomRound() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(10) + 15;
}

}
